# Is there an accepted name for this type of enumerable operation?

Tags: c#, linq, terminology, list-comprehension

I often find myself needing to traverse trees of hierarchial objects and perform operations on each item along the way. Is there a generally accepted name for this kind of operation in the list comprehension vernacular? I ask because I remember first learning about python's [zip function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) back before it had an equivalent in the .net framework and thinking it had an unusual but appropriate name.

Here are a couple of generalized methods that recurse up and down tree structures and yield each item as they're encountered.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Ancestors<T>(T source, Func<T, T> selector)
{
    do
    {
        yield return source;
        source = selector(source);
    } while (!Equals(source, default(T)));
}

public static IEnumerable<T> Descendents<T>(T source,
                                            Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> selector)
{
    var stack = new Stack<T>();
    stack.Push(source);
    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        source = stack.Pop();
        yield return source;
        var items = selector(source);
        if (items != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                stack.Push(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Some kind of filtered tree traversal ? I don't know if this has a particular name. I don't think it has.

Comment: The 2nd one is doing a depth-first search. Not sure the 2nd one has a name, since although it's called `Ancestors` depending on the selector function, it doesn't need to actually follow the 'parent' at all (e.g. it could do anything, e.g. select a 'best' child node)

Comment: @George: Exactly, `Ancestors` implies a certain kind of hierarchial relationship. In reality it could just as easily be used to traverse a doubly linked list in either direction or follow any kind of arbitrary trail.

Comment: The same goes for `Descendents` which, to use a genealogy example, could be used to simultaneously follow a persons ancestors on both their fathers and mothers side at every level.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that the selector gives the child nodes, your second method is a "right first depth first" traversal.  That is, if you had

```
      A
    /  \
   B     C
  / \   / \
 D   E F   G
```

Then you get A, C, G, F, B, E, D. You get "G" before "B" because "depth first" goes as deep as it can before it tries another branch.  In your particular example you'll get C before B because it prioritizes right over left.

If you changed it to

```
foreach (var item in items.Reverse())
```

then you'd get a left-first-depth-first traversal, which is how most people think of depth first traversal.

If you changed the stack to a queue then it would become a "breadth first" traversal.  A, B, C, D, E, F, G. You do an entire "level" at a time.

There are other traversals as well. Notice that depth-first and breadth-first searches both have the property that parent nodes come before child nodes. You can also have "post-order" traversals in which every node comes after its children.

Binary trees also have an "inorder" traversal. The inorder traversal of this tree is D, B, E, A, F, C, G.  That is, every left child comes before all its ancestors, and every right child comes after all its ancestors.  As an exercise, can you write an in-order traversal on a binary tree?

Comment: PseudoCode exercise response: `Function Inorder(Tree){if (Tree == null){return;} Inorder(Tree.Left); Output(Tree.Value); Inorder(Tree.Right);}`

Comment: @Brian: Super. Can you do it without recursion?

Comment: @Eric, you need to emulate the call stack using normal stack of nodes and the return address using a flag for each node on the stack. When you pop the stack, you check the flag whether to 1. “recurse” left or 2. (yield) return the current node and “recurse” right. There is no need for a third state, which is basically a tail call optimization.

Comment: I think this does it:         `public static void Inorder2(Node x)
        {
            Node cur = x;
            Stack<Node> q = new Stack<Node>();
            while (true)
            {
                while (cur != null)
                {
                    q.Push(cur);
                    cur = cur.Left;
                }
                if (q.Count == 0) return;
                cur = q.Pop();
                Trace.Write(cur.Value + " ");
                cur = cur.Right;
            }
        }`

Comment: I didn't trust my recursion emulation skills, so I used C# this time, and a slight variation on this [`Node`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/04/19/every-binary-tree-there-is.aspx) class.  I ignored the case of passing `Inorder2` the empty tree (i.e., `null`).

Answer (score 1):

These are standard [Tree Traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) functions, also commonly known as "tree walking". It's difficult to give your examples standardised names because the concrete walking strategy is not known :)